# Type of singularity of $\sin(z)/z^3$ at $0$

Tags: complex-analysis

I would have thought that this is a pole of order $3$ but on the answers it says it is of order $2$. I don't see why...

Comment: What is the Taylor expansion of $\sin z$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\lim\limits_{z\to 0} \frac{\sin(z)}{z}=1$ so for small $z$, $$\frac{\sin(z)}{z^3} \sim 1 \frac{1}{z^2}=\frac{1}{z^2}$$

More formally, look at the Taylor series for $\sin(z)$:

$$\sin(z)=z-\frac{z^3}{3!}+\frac{z^5}{5!}+\dots$$.

So:

$$\frac{\sin(z)}{z^3}=\frac{1}{z^2}-\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{z^2}{5!}+\dots$$

Comment: I see. So when finding the residue, would it be $$\frac1{(2-1)!} \lim \limits_{z \rightarrow 0} \frac{d^{2-1}}{dz^{2-1}} (z-0)^2 f(z)$$???

Comment: Or you could just use the definition of residue http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexResidue.html since you already know the Laurent series.

Comment: What if we had at $0$: $$f(z)=\frac{\cosh (z) -1}{z^2}$$ When I expanded this, I didn't get any zero dividers so does that mean it is removable? The first term was $1/2$ so we can say for $f(0)$, let this equal $1/2$? Please confirm.

Comment: Also reply to your "Or you could just use the definition of residue..." comment, the residue is the coefficient of $1/(z-z_0)$ right? but there is no term that has this so wouldn't that mean the residue is zero? And not $1$?

Comment: Yup, the residue is 0.

Comment: So you cant use the limit formula for this question? That is so weird!

Comment: Whoever said you can't use the limit formula for the residue?

Comment: But it gives $1$ as the residue........... from the limit formula

Comment: Why would they be different?

Comment: @snowman they aren't, check your computations

Comment: ohhh silly me. Thanks. Also please would you answer my comment about the $\cosh$? I would really appreciate it. It would clear things up.

Comment: Yes, $(\cosh z - 1)/z^2$ has a removable singularity at $z=0$.

Comment: @mjqxxxx just curious, wouldn't the residue of all removable singularities be $0$ because there would be no $1/(z-z_0)$ term in the expansion...

Comment: Correct, there's no residue at a removable singularity.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: what does the power series for $\sin(z)$ look like? What happens if you divide it by $z^3$?